# Get all URL used by routes in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes

I'm working on a website using Symfony 2 in which each user will have a profile page reachable at `domain.com/username` (like many social websites offer).

To achieve this I need to check if the wanted URL is available when a user wants to pick one.
I would like to know if there is a way in Symfony to get all URL used by routes defined in routing configuration to automatically forbid those routes as usernames.

Thank you

Comment: You can obtain an instance of `Route` from `container` with `container->get('router')`. From there you can access a method called `getRouteCollection()`  which would return an instance of `RouteCollection` and from there call method `all()` that would return an array of each route.

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank a lot !

Comment: @ibi0tux, according to your case, username and the route have  1:1 relationship. if I am not mistaken, then  as long as the username is unique in your table, the route will always be unique.

Comment: My problem wasn't about making each username unique, but preventing users to choose username that would match paths in my routing configuration (the other pages of the website)

Comment: Another approach is to grab the url matcher service and then simply do $matcher->match('/' . $proposedUsername).  If you get a match then the name is not valid.

Comment: I didn't know there was a such service in Symfony, your approach could be quite interesting in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Now I know that I have system routers starting with `application_frontend` and `application_backend`.

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
application_frontend:
    resource: "@ApplicationFrontendBundle/Controller"
    prefix:   /
    type:     annotation

application_backend:
    resource: "@ApplicationBackendBundle/Controller"
    prefix:   /backend
    type:     annotation
```

I'm using my controllers as services but you don't have to.

**controller.yml**

```
services:
    application_frontend.controller.profile:
        class: Application\FrontendBundle\Controller\ProfileController
        arguments:
            - @router
            - @doctrine_common_inflector

    doctrine_common_inflector:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector
```

You should refactor `explode` bit and do some cleaning such as remove `action` from the route names. I left it little dirty for you to see what exactly I'm doing there. Based on your application, this code might change. It just gives you an idea how it can be done.

**ProfileController**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
# .......

/**
 * @Route("profile", service="application_frontend.controller.profile")
 */
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    private $router;
    private $inflector;

    public function __construct(
        RouterInterface $router,
        Inflector $inflector
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->inflector = $inflector;
    }

    /**
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Route("/step_one")
     */
    public function stepOneAction()
    {
        $list = [];
        $myRoutes = ['application_frontend', 'application_backend'];
        $routeCollection = $this->router->getRouteCollection();

        foreach ($routeCollection->all() as $key => $value)
        {
            $data = $value->getDefaults();

            if (isset($data['_controller'])) {
                foreach ($myRoutes as $routePrefix) {
                    if (strstr($data['_controller'], $routePrefix) !== false) {
                        $routeParts = explode(':', $data['_controller']);
                        $routeParts2 = explode('.', $routeParts[0]);

                        $list[] = end($routeParts2). '/' . $this->inflector->tableize(end($routeParts));
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($list);
        exit;
    }
}
```

You can compare list against `app/console debug:router` command.

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => country/index_action
    [1] => country/list_action
    [2] => default/index_action
    [3] => default/list_action
    [4] => profile/step_one_action
    [5] => profile/step_two_action
    [6] => profile/step_one_process_action
    [7] => profile/step_two_process_action
    [8] => security/index_action
    [9] => security/login_action
    [10] => security/logout_action
    [11] => api/json_action
    [12] => api/xml_action
    [13] => api/json_xml_action
    [14] => default/index_action
    [15] => default/list_action
    [16] => default/secret_action
    [17] => superadmin/index_action
    [18] => superadmin/list_action
    [19] => twitter/list_action
    [20] => twitter/create_tweet_action
    [21] => user/list_action
    [22] => user/create_action
)
```